# How to ignore ng-non-bindable for a child element (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

So if I have something like this:

```
<section ng-non-bindable>
    <!-- Lots of elements -->
    <p my-amazing-directive></p>
</section>
```

How can I make sure that `my-amazing-directive` gets compiled?

Comment: I've already tried creating a custom directive with a priority of 1001, but not even that directive gets compiled inside an `ng-non-bindble`.

Comment: Check the Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

```
The ngNonBindable directive tells AngularJS not to compile or bind the contents of the current DOM element, including directives on the element itself that have a lower priority than ngNonBindable. This is useful if the element contains what appears to be AngularJS directives and bindings but which should be ignored by AngularJS. This could be the case if you have a site that displays snippets of code, for instance.```

it says you shouldn't compile things inside ng-non-bindable

Comment: @RichardFazzi - Thanks for your comment. I did read the docs prior to asking this question, that's how I came up with the idea of maybe making this work with a higher priority directive. I'm asking if there's a way to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for miss guide you, please, could you explain what do you want this for? what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a simple way to accomplish what you want.

Under the hood, the `ng-non-bindable` directive uses:

```
`terminal: true`
```

From the Docs:

> ### terminal
>
> If set to `true` then the current priority will be the last set of directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is undefined). Note that expressions and other directives used in the directive's template will also be excluded from execution.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - terminal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-non-bindable Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Comment: Yeah, I also found that in the docs. Well, thanks! Guess I'll have to think about something else.

Comment: I am curious as to your use case. Why do you want to do this?